# Can you modify files in a repository right after issuing maven compile install?

Tags: maven

For projects which take a long time to build, can you issue the maven compile or maven install commands and then continue making changes to the files in your repository, without these changes affecting the outcome of the maven install command?

Is a snapshot automatically taken when the command is issued? If not, is there a way to request that maven take a snapshot of the project when a command is issued, so that you could continue making changes after that snapshot?

Comment: Please describe more in detail what you like to achieve and what the problem is you have?

Answer (score 0):

If you build locally, you should not be changing files while you build because you might break the build.

If you build on a build server, it depends:

- If you run a `clean package` or `clean install`, then there is just one checkout at the beginning. After that it should not be a problem to make further commits.
- If you build a release with Maven release plugin, you should probably be more careful. I haven't actually seen any problems in nature yet, but since the Maven release plugin commits to git/svn itself, you might cause problems when committing during the build on the same branch.